# UIPopover contentSize is changing in runtime

Tags: ios, ios13, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

We are facing an issue where popover size is getting changed when a UIActionSheet style of alertController is used inside a popover. This is happening after we upgraded our code base iOS13

Sample Code: https://github.com/Sundeep-manne/UIPopover.git

Comment: I have added the GitHub link for sample code as well

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Presenting an UIAlerController with preferredStyle .actionSheet from a popover. The popover frame grows by 13px for both the presentation and dismissal (via cancel) of the actionSheet. This was not happening prior to iOS 13.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is Apple bug. 
I experience it on Xcode 11.1, but on Xcode 11.2.1 when displaying the ActionSheet I'm getting the crash:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController () of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet from UINavigationController (). The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'

So the answer is: to use ActionSheet on iPad you need to provide sourceView and sourceRect in popoverPresentationController of your UIAlertController. More info:
https://medium.com/@nickmeehan/actionsheet-popover-on-ipad-in-swift-5768dfa82094

Apple docs:

> On iPad, UIKit requires that you display an action sheet inside a popover.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/getting_the_user_s_attention_with_alerts_and_action_sheets

Comment: That seems unrelated, using `sourceView` / `sourceRect` always been required on iPads.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Maybe it was always been required, but the author of the question is not using sourceView / sourceRect in the example code.
In Xcode 11.1, the above is the reason of bug that the author experience.